# can't get event.preventDefault() or return false to work. been trying from morning until evening

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have been creating a form that for users to log into my site that uses jquery to preform login validation and also has a PHP fallback just in case Javascript is disabled. The user's login form in itself is a lightbox. The way I am trying to design it is so that if there's an error, the error message will appear directly in the lightbox without closing it or redirecting the user. I am basically checking to things. If the 'username' and 'password' field have been filled and if the 'username' and 'password' fields can be validated. Javascript works perfectly when I check to see if the fields have been filled out. The 'return false' works, the error message appears inside the lightbox and everything is 'honky dory'. but when it comes to validation, I use ajax to check the database and if there's a problem it does not return false.

Actually what's happening is that the error message 'will' appear at the top of the lightbox for a split second and then it submits to PHP and PHP is redirecting it.

So here is the breakdown of the code.

```
$('body').on('click','[name=submit11]',function(){
     $('.error').remove();
     var req = ['username','password'];
     var div = '#login_form';
     validate(div,req);
     if($('.error').length == 0){
        var login = true;
        var username = $(this).siblings('[name=username]').val();
        var password = $(this).siblings('[name=password]').val();
        $.post('../ajax/multipurpose.php',    {login:login,username:username,password:password},function(data){
            if($.trim(data) != ''){
                $('#login_form').prepend("<div class='error'>"+data+"</div>");
            }                                                                             
        });
    }
    if($('.error').length > 0){
        event.stopPropagation();
        return false;
    }
});
```

The validate function is a custom function I am using in jquery and that's working perfectly. The problem begins inside the second if statement after the ajax has been performed. In this if statement, there will be an error if ajax finds an error. Here is the code that's inside the multipurpose.php page.

```
//Used to validate the username and password via ajax
if(isset($_POST["login"])):
    $username = trim($_POST["username"]);
    $password = trim($_POST["password"]);
    if(!$found_user = User::authenticate($username,$password)):
        echo "Username/Password combination is invalid.";
    endif;
endif;
```

Another problem that I noticed is that if there is an error and I type alert($('.error').length) the value of 0 will show in the alert box and then after I click on "OK" in the alert box the value will appear in the lightbox and then submit to PHP. This is only for the ajax portion, not for the validate() custom function. Here is the code for the validate() function just in case anyone needs to see it.

```
function validate(div,fields){
    var boxes = ['pounds_or_kilos','activity'];
    $(div+' .error').remove();
    $(fields).each(function(key,value){
        if($.inArray(value,boxes) == -1){
            text = $('[name='+value+']').val();
            if($.trim(text) == ''){
                removeLoader();
                addError(div,value);
            }
        }else if(!$('[name='+value+']:checked').length){
            addError(div,value);
        }
    });
}
```

I've tried EVERYTHING inside that second if statement to stop it from submitting. I've tried return false...in which I use in MANY areas of the site without problems, I tried event.preventDefault(), I've tried putting an e inside the click function and using e.preventDefault(), I've also tried the event.stopPropagation() and still nothing. Someone please help me.

Comment: It already 'is' at the bottom of the event handler. If I go outside of those final brackets I'll be outside of the click event itself.

Comment: Look at that second if statement. Don't you see it's already at the very bottom after everything including the ajax has already been run?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$.post` is async. So if there is error, you append it after the second check `if($('.error').length > 0)` and so you didn't prevent form submit behaviour.

What you can do is prevent this behaviour in all cases and if no error regarding ajax request, then submit `form` manually (using native DOM method), e.g:

```
$('body').on('click', '[name=submit11]', function() {
  var form = $(this).closest('form').get(0);
  $('.error').remove();
  var req = ['username', 'password'];
  var div = '#login_form';
  validate(div, req);
  if ($('.error').length == 0) {
    var login = true;
    var username = $(this).siblings('[name=username]').val();
    var password = $(this).siblings('[name=password]').val();
    $.post('../ajax/multipurpose.php', {
      login: login,
      username: username,
      password: password
    }, function(data) {
      if ($.trim(data) != '') {
        $('#login_form').prepend("<div class='error'>" + data + "</div>");
      }
      else {
         form.submit();
      }
    });
  }
  return false;
});
```

Comment: I'm looking at your code and I only see 2 lines that you added. I am seeing that you set a variable and then you added an else statement to run if there happens to be an error coming from ajax. I tried it but I'm getting the same problem. It doesn't work. Maybe it's my fault for not mentioning that the button I am using is an "type=submit" button and not a "type=button" so the default action of the button is to submit. There's no need to add an 'else' statement telling it to submit if there's no error, because the problem that I'm having is that it's submiting when I don't want it to.

Comment: I actually had an idea from reading your comment and I made a little progress, What I did is I added event.preventDefault() directly above the $('.error').remove() and it's not submitting anymore. The problem I'm having now is that I can't get it to submit properly when there's not an error. How can I disable the preventDefault() when there's not an error?

Comment: `I can't get it to submit properly when there's not an error` In my example, `form.submit()` would submit the form as needed. So did you copy/paste exact same code as i posted it? BTW, if `#login_form` is your form, then you could instead use `document.getElementById('login_form').submit();` which is the same as `$('#login_form').get(0).submit();`. And your main error is that you forget than ajax is async. And FYI, `return false;` is shorthand for `event.preventDefault();` and `event.stopPropagation();`

Comment: I did not copy and paste your code, because most of your code was the same as mine. I just copied and pasted the parts that you added and deleted the parts from my code that wern't on yours and it didn't work. I can't use return false, I must use event.preventDefault() because if I use return false, the rest of the code will not run. It quits. event.preventDefault() just stops it from submitting, I am not yet familiar with event.stopPropagation(); Now I need to figure out how to override the event.preventDefault() when errors are not found.

Comment: You should just copy paste this code and set return statement at end of handler, just as in this posyed snippet

Comment: The code that I used was exactly the same as the code you gave me. Cutting and pasting is irrelevent. The bottom line is that the code that I used was exactly the same as what you showed me but it didn't work.. I will close this topic because I finally figured out the solution.. I passed the "e" variable into the click callback function, used e.preventDefault() and in the else statement I used $('#login_form form').submit(). So even though the code you gave me didn't work I should still thank you for giving me the ideas I needed to fix the problem

Comment: I guess you were testing it on Firefox, this browser is the only one from all major ones to not use global event model but still you wouldn't have this issue using `return false;` instead of `event.preventDefault();` (while not passing event as handler parameter), so i'm still not sure what could be wrong in my posted code. Anyway, i'm glad you have fixed it :)